# how to create like button using jquery, ajax and codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

> **View**

I have tried to create like button here. And everytime i click like button it increases by 1. Here how do i put value from database using `foreach()` loop and feeding it in jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#like").click(function() {
    var id='1069347886434951';//this is not artist who likes
    var creation_id= 1;
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>creations/like_creation",
    data:'id='+id + '&creation_id=' +creation_id,//after its split, the split function gives an array
    success: function(response){        
      try{
        if(response=='true'){ 
          var newValue = parseInt($("#like").text()) + 1;            
          $("#"+voteId+'_result').html(newValue);// adds the value to no of like on the client side
        }else{
          alert('Sorry Unable to update..');
        }
      }catch(e) {   
        alert('Exception while request..');
      }   
    },
    error: function(){            
      alert('Error while request..');
    }
   });
    });
  });
  </script>
```

> **Controller**
>    The controller inserts the value in database. If you put the value using postman it will return true using json upto ajax. I have tried it in postman and it does.

```
public function like_creation(){
    //$artist_id=$this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $artist_id=$this->input->post('id');

    //bring creation id from the database when fed using foreach loop
    $creation_id=$this->input->post('creation_id');
    //$up_like1 =0;
    $data1=array(
    'id'=> $this->input->post('id'),//bring it from artist_infors
    'creation_id'=>  $this->input->post('creation_id'),
    'artist_who_likes'=> $artist_id ,

    );

    $query=$this->hbmodel->insert_like($data1);     


    $status= "true";

    echo $status;
}
```

> **Model**

```
 public function no_likes($artist_id, $creation_id)
{
    $sql="SELECT count(like_id) as num from likes as l where id='$artist_id'  and creation_id= $creation_id";
    //artist id has to determine whether it is user himself or the one whom       he/she tries to follow
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

> MySQL qUERY

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `likes` (
`like_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id` varchar(500) COLLATE utf16_bin DEFAULT NULL,//the artist id whose creation is fed
`creation_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`artist_who_likes` varchar(500) COLLATE utf16_bin DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`like_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=29 ;
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i am not able to create like button using the above code. can u find what's wrong with it

Comment: Error messages? Console messages? Also what is the try catch doing? there is no code that throws an exception in your success. You need to return the counter, not true or false

Comment: huh? I think there is exception handling done in success.. there is try and catch. and there are no syntatical error. only code is not working

Comment: There is not NEED for exception handling. "Code not working" is not very helpful. There must be some error somewhere visible when looking at consoles or PHP errors

Comment: i have tried to explain about the problem that i got in the question on each part of the code from controller to view. also provied database code to help you to understand what i am trying to do

Comment: I do not see any issues by looking at the code. If there are no errors, the code should work or not run at all. Did you include jQuery? Do you have a $ not defined error? For example var creation_id=<?php echo $feed->creation_id ?> - if creationID is not numeric you will get an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121478/discussion-between-saugat-thapa-and-mplungjan).

Comment: No. I am not into code igniter, I am just trying to get as much information as possible. perhaps it was a JS issue which I can help with

Comment: yeah it is. ci is just to help u to use it when u try to find a solution. All the necessary code u need to build the like button

Comment: hey @mplungjan check the ajax part again i have edited the question. Replace php part and see if it helps for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($.trim(response) === 'true')
```

the problem is in the codition of success. the value comes from response but not compared properly with a string